# Has nontrivial solution in positive integers of a diophantine equation: $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Has nontrivial solution in positive integers of a [diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) as follows ?

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2$$

Where trivial solutions are $x_i=y_j$.

Can you send me any reference for this question?

Comment: A general solution can be obtained simply by choosing different sets of signs in a quaternion norm identity, analogous to how the general solution of the sum of two squares equation of the same type can be obtained by considering norms of Gaussian integers.

Comment: Or you can use that $x_1^2-y_1^2=N$ has non-trivial solutions in integers iff $N$ is not 2 mod 4.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A024367](https://oeis.org/A025367)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many non-trivial solutions.  By [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), *every* natural number can be represented as a sum of $4$ squares (with $0^2$ allowed), and [Jacobi's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem) gives the number $r_4(n)$ of representations of $n$.  Note that $r_4(n)$ double counts solutions, but since $r_4(n)$ is arbitrarily large infinitely often, this clearly implies that there exist infinitely many $n$ with two distinct representations (without $0^2$).

Answer (score 4):

Besides [Jacobi's four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem), you can also show that there are nontrivial solutions because there are $k^4$ quadruples of integers from $0$ through $k-1$, and all of the sums of squares are at most $4k^2$ which is $o(k^4)$. So, the average number of ways to write a number up to $n$ as a sum of four squares goes to infinity as $n \to \infty$.

In Mathematica, you can ask for distinct ways to express an integer as a sum of four squares as follows:

```
PowersRepresentations[100,4,2]
{{0, 0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 6, 8}, {1, 1, 7, 7}, {1, 3, 3, 9}, {1, 5, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 4, 8}, {5, 5, 5, 5}}
Length[PowersRepresentations[10000, 4, 2]]
67
```

Comment: Thank to You very much, there is geometry of this problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257693/inspired-from-british-flag-theorem